# Should questions about sizing plumbing for outdoor fixtures be on topic?

Tags: discussion

Recently there was a question about [determining the size of pipe needed to supply a water trough](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/106426/33), which received a vote to close.  There was then a discussion in the comments, as to whether or not the question was on topic.

> [image]

I've decided to ask the question here, to get the opinions of a broader audience.

Is this question on topic?

Answer (score 9):

I think it is on-topic.

Questions about what size wire to run to a detached garage or lamp post are on-topic.

I don't think there would be any debate if the pipe was running to a detached garage. What difference is it if it's a backyard pond, fountain, barn or water trough?

Comment: I agree. I can't see any reason why it wouldn't be on topic.

Comment: Seconded as on-topic -- people who live out in the sticks sometimes have slightly unusual home-improvement concerns because of the larger land areas and paucity of services involved, but their issues are just as valid as those us city slickers have!

Comment: I agree. My comment about the ISS was to make a point: in this case, "on topic" had little or nothing to do with the location of the work, but everything to do with the techniques used.

Answer (score 3):

The question is very much on topic. Plenty of folks live on more rural property that they consider home just as much as city dwellers that live on small lots. And those small lots these days could very well have a chicken watering gadget that an owner wants to plumb some distance from the house with a low pressure piping system.

As a matter of fact the folks on the rural properties are probably just as much or more inclined to be DIY types as the small lot city dwellers.